# Raspberry Pi High CPU Usage With Sense Hat

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am getting 75% or higher CPU usage levels for any Python application I write that uses sense hat. Best I can tell, just including the line "from sense_hat import SenseHat" results in the high CPU usage regardless of what code follows. Seems to be the case even if the app does not really call any sense hat functions.

Using RPi 3 with latest updates for Raspian. Python v2.7.9.

I am a rank beginner at Python and RPi in general. Probably missing something obvious, but would appreciate some help/suggestions. Thanks!

A short Python code that exhibits the behavior described above follows. PLEASE NOTE: even if I comment out all of the code dealing with the HTTP Server as well as the t = sense.get_temperature()" line, still get 75% CPU usage.  Thanks again for looking and for any suggestions!!

```
/#! /usr/bin/python
import os
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import sys
from sense_hat import SenseHat
import time

PORT = 8080

sense = SenseHat()


file = open("/home/pi/webpy/test.txt", "a")
file.write("Temperature Data:\n")
file.flush()

t = sense.get_temperature()
string_t = str(t) + "\n"
file.write( string_t)
file.flush()

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port ", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: You sample example starts whole http server. I am not sure if that counts as a minimal.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post to better explain the high CPU usage results even without the HTTP server code. Should have been more clear.

Comment: OK. Two things. 1. Your example still does start http server, so it's not easy to copy-paste it onto "workbench". 2. I strongly suggest asking this on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/. You will get much more chance of getting an answer, as your problem is not a general programming problem, but a rather specific to the device and you will get better visibility among the people who are more experienced with it, and have better chance of reproducing the issue. (I am not sure if a mod can move this.) Cheers.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com. Sounds good!

Comment: What is "Sense Hat"?

Comment: Sense hat is a Raspberry Pi plug in module that has imu, environment sensors and a led array. You can find on RPi site or amazon.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have the solution to your problem. 
check out the github thread https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6237[1](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6237)

I did what @rsteca suggested and it worked. Quoting the solution here:

> I had the exact same problem and this is what I did to solve it: $
>   sudo apt-get install libatlas3-base $ sudo update-alternatives
>   --config libblas.so.3 choose the libatlas option $ sudo update-alternatives --config liblapack.so.3 choose the libatlas option
>   $ sudo aptitude purge libopenblas-{base,dev}